# How to edit Wooсommerce admin "Add fee" formula?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to edit Wooсommerce admin "Add fee" formula as percentage, where i can find it in source?

Confirm window asks "Enter a fixed amount or percentage to apply as a fee"

I need to edit fee formula like this
(cart_total*100)/96.5

Comment: You just need to calculate the formula yourself first and add the calculated amount in  the field…

Comment: i need to automate this process

Comment: What have you tried yet? please provide your code.

Comment: i cant find where in WooCommerce source code of confirm window "Enter a fixed amount or percentage to apply as a fee" to edit this as i need